# JavaScript HTML validation function only works when the form elements are all filled

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I'm making sign in form with submit. What I want to do is to alert when there is blank in the form. But the function only works when all of the form are filled. Here's the HTML and JS code. The result is the same using `onsubmit` inside of the HTML or `addEventListener("submit" function name)`

HTML : It's basically a form for sign in / ordering.

```
<form id="registration" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate();" action="phplink">
  <p> <label for="custName">Name : </label>
  <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" required="required" /> </p>
</form>
```

JS :

```
function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var r = document.getElementById("registration");
    var cname = r.cname.value;
    var errMsg = "";

    if (cname == "") {
        errMsg += "Please enter your Name.\n";
    }

    if (errMsg.length != 0) {
        alert(errMsg);
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I solved it with this. if (cname == "") {
        errMsg += "Please enter your Name.\n"; result = false;
    }

Answer (score 1):

The validation constrains, such as your `required="required"` are validated *before* your browser will trigger a submit event. If the validation fails (a value to a required field is not provided) it will *not* submit your form.

If you want to do the validation using JavaScript instead of the validation constraint attributes, you either need to remove the `required="required"` attribute (together with any other similar attributes) or you can add the [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission) attribute to your form to indicate that it should not perform this validation on submit.

If you use the latter, you can still use [`formElement.reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) to see if all the elements satisfy their validation constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a **required** attribute to each field that shouldn’t be blank, it’ll prevent form submission with empty fields, like this...

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have several problem. on submit must pass event => **onsubmit="return validate(event);"** .
you must first defined result and thats your flag => **var result = false** .
if you want show alert then input dont need required attribute.

so this is your Fixed Code;

```
function validate(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var result = true;
        var r = document.getElementById("registration");
        var cname = r.cname.value;
        var errMsg = "";
  
        if (cname == "") {
            errMsg += "Please enter your Name.\n";
        }

        if (errMsg.length != 0) {
            alert(errMsg);
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
        }
```

Comment: "_on submit must pass event_" [Not entirely true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) (it will work without passing it), though it is definitely recommended.

Comment: then must use addEventListener and e.preventdeafault() can work.